# How to set a Folder location in application.properties?

Tags: spring, file, command-line, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a Spring Project which creates XML Files.
How can I set the Folder location, to where the files should be written in application.properties?

In my Code:

```
StreamResult result2 = new StreamResult(new File("D:\\HealthCheck\\status.xml"));
```

Here I'm passing the file location in the code.

But how can I set in the application.properties file so that we can change the destination in the application.properties file and pass that file through command line.

How to achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All properties you set in `application.properties` are available through Spring's `Environment` class. You can just inject the `Environment` object into your class and read a config param like this:

**application.properties:**

```
myApp.folder=D:\\HealthCheck
```

**MyClass.java:**

```
@Component
public class MyClass{

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    public void doStuff(){
       String folder = environment.getProperty("myApp.folder");
       StreamResult result2 = new StreamResult(new File(folder + "\\status.xml"));
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the package of the Environment?

Comment: Thanks @Tom
One more silly question.
When I use Environment, it shows  

    org.springframework.core.env.Environment Environemnt env;

How do I import that package?
Add a dependency?

Comment: The Environment class is in the spring-core JAR which you should automatically have as a dependency in a Spring Boot project